# Redshift locks table very often

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table "A" which runs every hour on my redshift database.It runs from an orchestration tool AIRFLOW.

The process has certain inserts in the table so in few stages we are inserting some data In the table "A".The issue is that this table "A" is being used by lot of the people for ADHOC queries, so lot of select statements run.

So it happens that generally when its the time of inserting the data in the table "A" there are also lot of select statements trying to query it and hence creates a lock.

Please advice how I can prevent this lock so that it doesn't lock it that often.

Comment: Redshift doesn't use write locks the way some databases do.  It uses MVCC which allows for lots of locks to coexist while work is progressing forward.  So having locks isn't a problem per se but there are cases when it can be.  What updating process is being used on table_A?  What issues are you experiencing?  How are COMMITs being issued by Airflow and by the user sessions?

Comment: @BillWeiner Sure, so what happens is we build a table called "accounts" every hour so when we ran the tests initially on the table it ran fine in the airflow in redshift but we have analysis tool looker which creates our dashboards actually and most of the people in the firm are running queries through looker UI so it creates lock while it access data through looker.  So please suggest how can we avoid this? How to avoid locks in general  bc locks are happening often also can join create locks in the redshift database ?

Comment: The word I lock into here is "build".  I'm seeing you might be doing an update of the entire table, yes?  There are 3 common ways to do this - "truncate/insert", "delete/insert", and "swap & drop".  Are you running a process that looks like any of these?  Each has its own pros/cons and each can lead to different issues if not used appropriately.  For example TRUNCATE can lead to seeing an empty table and also needs an exclusive lock.  This is not the best option when others are actively using the table.  Is this the process you have for building accounts?

Comment: @BillWeiner Give me sometime to explain you the full process but its mostly swap and drop for the final tables , the table runs in 3 stages until it makes it final swap and drop with the 3rd stage

Comment: Swap and drop is a good option in this use case.  However, you will need to make sure there is a COMMIT between the swaps and the drop.  Users could be accessing the old version of the table and these READ LOCKs will hold off the DROP.  Some will leave the old table around for a day or 2 as a little bit of history for error recovery and to decouple the swap from the drop even further.  A separate DAG will clean up the old table versions that are older than the prescribed interval.  I'll wait for the complete write-up but thought this info would be helpful

Comment: Yes you are right we are doing a swap and drop which means that there is always a lock on the older version so swap cannot happen Do you think making views can help it ? But still the tables which are running on the view when they get truncated the view will also stop working hence making all the other queries kill or stop. What are the possible solution here ?

Comment: So to be clear the lock blocking progress is the read-lock on the old version (previous hour's update) of the account table, right?  This makes it so the next iteration of the update process cannot drop this "old" version in order to swap again.  This means that users are continuing to use old data for more than the update interval of the table.  Do I understand the situation correctly?

Comment: No, adding a view to the situation won't help.  Also you used the word "truncate" in describing the view update - I'm assuming that this IS NOT a use of the SQL command TRUNCATE.

Comment: @BillWeiner Yes you are right can't drop bc the users are reading from the old table and we can't drop that version. Also I was just thinking about the view part but we haven't done anything about it.That was just a though process please guide us how we can solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the clarification.  So you have 2 issues: 1) your ETL process stalls when the "old" table is still in use AND 2) some users are accessing out of date information.  You will likely need to address both but let's dig into #1 first.

To solve #1 you just need to not depend on the locks existing on the old table version.  The easiest way to do this is to just add a timestamp to the table name for the "swap" step.  you are running a process something like:

1. new data is put in a "new" table
2. you are dropping "tableA_old" (from the previous run of the process)
3. in a transaction you are renaming "tableA" to "tableA_old" and renaming "new" to "tableA"
4. you are dropping "tableA_old" but this drop hangs until the table is no longer in use (locked)

The problem happens when step 4 from the previous run isn't complete when the nest iteration runs.  When this happens step #3 fails because "tableA_old" already exists.  So to solve this don't reuse the same name for "tableA_old".  Use something like "tableA_20220216_22_old" (date plus hour).

Now this will stop the renaming of the table from failing but you COULD have many previous iterations hanging on the drop in step #4.  This isn't a problem if it happens at a low level (1 or 2 hours of old versions hanging around) Redshift will keep track which sessions are using which versions of tableA and airflow can do this as well.  But if you have days and days of old versions hanging around this can fill up disks and steal other system resources.

This brings us to issue #2 - how are user sessions being kept up to date with the changing version of tableA?  There is no limit to how long a user can keep a transaction open and thus no limit on how long they can have a read lock active or how old the data is that they are accessing.  There are configurations that can be set that can help - like "idle session timeout" but this doesn't directly ensure that locks cannot be kept a very long time.  To achieve this usually takes a few tactics - idle timeouts, long session daemons (kill sessions that are really long lived like > day), configuring BI tools to issues COMMITs/ROLLBACKs, use of autocommit, and training of users.